# Plotting image intensity vs (x,y) in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a 3D plot of the intensity of a grayscale image vs (x,y) coordinates of a pixel. I wrote the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
f=imread('peppers.png');
f=rgb2gray(f);
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:1:384,1:1:512);
mesh(x,y,f(x,y))
```

The error reported is:

> ??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

**Note:** The dimensions of the image are <384x512 uint8>

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code and how to plot the intensity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code: The `meshgrid` command creates two matrices of size `512 x 384` instead of `384 x 512`. Simply switch the two inputs of `meshgrid` to solve this. Then you don't need to call `f(x,y)` inside `mesh`. The correct syntax is:

```
mesh(x,y,f)
```

where `x` and `y` are the matrices you created, and `f` is the image. 
That way, the plot is generated as correctly.

Note: you could also just call

```
mesh(f)
```

as MATLAB can generate the vectors `x` and `y` automatically.

Comment: It gives another error: "Data dimensions must agree"

Comment: Did you switch the inputs of `meshgrid`, so it is now `meshgrid(1:1:512,1:1:384);`?

Comment: Yes, still "Warning: CData must be double or single unless it is used only as a texture data "

Comment: Have you tried converting `f` to double? Though this is not needed on my machine with R2014b...

Comment: Convert `f` to `double`.  It should work. +1 btw to you @hbaderts.

Comment: @hbaderts - I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment.  Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab